# convert only non-empty list to tuple in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

how do i convert this:

```
[[], [], [('ef', 1)], [], [('cd', 3)], [('ab', 2)]]
```

into this:

```
[[], [], ['ef', 1], [], ['cd', 3], ['ab', 2]]
```

i understand that to convert a tuple into a list, we would simply use list(tuple), or if it is a list like [(1,2),(3,4)] we can use map. How would i do this with the tuples that are within a list that is inside the main list, while the empty lists remain unchanged?

Comment: do those lists contain at most one tuple?

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> my_list = [[], [], [('ef', 1)], [], [('cd', 3)], [('ab', 2)]]

>>> [list(*el) for el in my_list]
[[], [], ['ef', 1], [], ['cd', 3], ['ab', 2]]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> l = [[], [], [('ef', 1)], [], [('cd', 3)], [('ab', 2)]]
>>> import itertools
>>> [list(itertools.chain(*item)) for item in l]
[[], [], ['ef', 1], [], ['cd', 3], ['ab', 2]]
```

This will also handle multiple tuples per list element (if that's what is desired):

```
>>> l = [[], [], [('ef', 1)], [], [('cd', 3),('ab', 2)]]
>>> [list(itertools.chain(*item)) for item in l]
[[], [], ['ef', 1], [], ['cd', 3, 'ab', 2]]
```

Comment: Deleted my answer in favor of this one.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
>>> lis = [[], [], [('ef', 1)], [], [('cd', 3)], [('ab', 2)]]
>>> [list(x[0]) if x else x for x in lis]
[[], [], ['ef', 1], [], ['cd', 3], ['ab', 2]]
```